# Find webparts with Search Box

Tags: 2013, 2010, web-part, sharepoint-server, search

I need to find my custom webparts with the search box. I couldn't find a way to index my web parts. The goal would be to have the web parts (titles?) displayed in the search result, and when you click one you get redirected to the page the web part is embedded.
What is the correct/fastest solution? I thought I could find something pretty easily, instead I didn't really find an answer.
The target platform is SharePoint Server 2010, but would be great to be also portable to SP 2013.

Thank you very much!
Alex.